# DRY partials with Assemble.io front-matter

Tags: yaml, dry, templating, assemble

I'm wondering how to make re-usable html partials with Assemble.

What I would like to do is just simply override front-matter of my new template that references the component I want.  See below:

Below is my-list.hbs(references my-list.yml)

```
    ---
    horiz-list: "<%= my-list %>"
    ---
    {{> horiz-list}}
```

Below is horiz-list.hbs(references horiz-list.yml)

```
   <ul class="horiz-list">
     {{#each horiz-list}}
     <li>{{.}}</li>
     {{/each}}
   </li>
```

Yml files are just lists of things like bananas, apples, oranges, or whatever.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

NOTE: The only thing I have seen about re-usable components so far is a stack-overflow that talked about extending the page using handlebars, but I couldn't find that this morning, and when I read it, it didn't seem like a straight-forward process.

Any help from the community would be much appreciated, given that assemble has some really nice features.

Thanks!

Comment: What would you like to have happen, and what's happening instead? You want to be able to use {{component}} in the partial? Right now do you get each item from `my-list` coming out in the ul?

Comment: I would like to be able to include generic items like "list" and then just override the default values for "list" so apples, bananas, and grapes could become carrot, celery, lettuce, if I point to a different data object.

Comment: To answer your other questions, nothing is coming out in the list now, unless I directly copy the code from the horiz-list partial.  I removed "component" because it was just meta-data and was confusing.  I think the main problem is that mark-down generators aren't smart enough to dynamically link to data objects.  I.E. that horiz-list gets assembled before it gets included in the other block, so I think there is no way to de-couple that html from the data object.  The way page contexts were explained to me, I thinking assemble can't do DRY components, unless there is an easy way to override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so... Trying to override data like this won't work, because it has a rigid order to how contexts are put together.

Thankfully, someone has already solved this problem for all of us.

This(below) is what I meant by "extending the page using handlebars"... It basically makes contexts in partials more flexible with data.

https://github.com/albogdano/handlebars-helper-mdpartial

There is also a node package that works with this to put keys for all the partials, and adds even more flexibility.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/assemble-partial-data